# How to check if a user is authenticated using AngularJs and a Django Rest backend?

Tags: angularjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

In a normal django project without rest, I did something like this in the templates:

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Hello {{request.user.username}}</p>
{% else %}
    <a href="/login/">Login</a>
```

How do I do the same thing using AngularJs? I am using the django-rest-auth, although I have not set up the login methods properly, so I am logging in from the admin panel to test things. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this sample project which will explain you how to use django-rest-auth api endpoints with angularjs: [django-rest-auth with angularjs](https://github.com/Tivix/angular-django-registration-auth)

This sample project is recommended by the django-rest-auth itself. Find more about it here: [documentation of django-rest-auth](http://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/introduction.html)